# What is the time complexity of for loop in which the counter starts from 1?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

May i know for the outer loop the time complexity is n+1-2? So its n-1

Example

```
for(int a=3; a<=n; a++){
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

So i have another question, assume that a < n , so the time complexity would be n-2? Thanks

Comment: So, as n grows large, say 1,000,000 rows, how important do you think it is whether your variable `a` starts at 0, 1, 2, 3, or 10?

Comment: hi phatfingers, i think it is important because let say n = 1000, when your counter is 100 , which means it will skip from 0 till 99. So when traversing, it will traverse from 100 until 1000. And I need the times of executions.  sry for broken english

Comment: The number of times that `println` is called is `n+1-3`. For example, if `n` is 5, the code will print 3,4,5. So `println` is called 3 times, which is `5+1-3`. So it's `n-2`.  If you change the condition to `a < n` then `println` would be called one less time, so `n-3` times. None of that has anything to do with time complexity. Time complexity describes how the code works when `n` is very large. The time complexity of your code is `O(n)`, It doesn't matter what the starting value for `a` is, because there's always an `n` that's much much larger than that starting value.

Comment: Big O notation is about characterizing complexity.  It is not about precisely determining execution times.  It is more about recognizing that some patterns can cause orders of magnitude of differences in effort as a dataset grows, while other patterns won't.

Comment: Consider a loop that does only 1 task and repeats n times.  Now, think about it doing 5 tasks repeating the same n times.  In both cases, it finishes in O(n) complexity, but one takes 5 times longer than the other, but both are considered to be of the same complexity.  At O(n), 1000 times n would yield in 1000 times the effort, but O(n*n) would yield 1,000,0000 times the effort.  Big O is really about understanding growth as you pile on more data.

Comment: hi user3386109, thanks for the detailed explaination but that's what my lecturer taught so far, so for the <i>println</i> executes for n-2 times. How about the for loop? it executes for n-3 times since the last iteration it will evaluate the condition?

Comment: hi phatfingers, thanks for detailed explaination. I am still learning this chapter and my lecturer started to teach us about algorithm analysis and a bit of big o notation. I have a bit information that are not really clear

Comment: Yes, the condition in the `for` loop will be checked one more time than the `println` is called, so `n-1` times, as you said in the question. (I didn't understand what you were trying to count when I read the question.)

Comment: Hi user3386109, that's what I am trying to count and really appreciate that u answered all my question. I think my question is not clear enough and I will try to state clearly next time. Also if a < n the time execution is n - 2?

Comment: Yes, the number of times the comparison is performed is `n-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop

```
for(int a=3; a<=n; a++){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

is running n-2 times, and if you compare it like `a < n`, the loop stops before 'a' reaches 'n', so n-3 times.

Since per definition for the Big-O-Notation constants don't matter the complexity of your loop is:

O(n-2) = O(n-3) = O(n).